# How to add items to a submenu on xubuntu 13.10

Tags: xubuntu, menu

I know how to add items to a menu applications on xubuntu and create submenus!

But I don't know how to create a submenu to show my home folder and its contents (subfolders and files),I want some thing similar to windows that I can browse folders and files from dropdown menus. Can someone help me? Is it possible to do it?

I know there is item called places on Xubuntu which shows recent documents, but that's not really it...

Answer (score 0):

There is the 'Directory Menu Plugin' which does this and comes pre-installed with the panel itself.

Integration into the existing application menu is not possible.

Comment: I added 'Directory Menu Plugin' but only list folders and not a content of a folder, beside that shows open a folder with file manager, I'm sorry but it's not the answer I need. Is there a way to do that?